# Как послать запрос tradeoffer с добавленными предметами

Tags: бот, steam-web-api

Хочу разобраться как послать tradeoffer сразу с предметами.
Если я просто посылаю запрос

```
https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner={id}&token={token}
```

Открывается окно с пустым предложением. Мне же надо, чтобы там были предметы. (Как например возврат предметов от бота csgolounge/dota2lounge)

Долго бродя по интернету, я понял, что нужно послать какой-то post запрос. Однако сколько  я не пытался, послать правильный у меня не получалось.

Какой именно пост запрос надо послать, чтобы пришел tradeoffer как от бота csgolouge/dota2lounge?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопросы на английском для enSO

Comment: Перевел на русский.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходим торговый бот.
Боты для таких целей есть уже готовые:

[Первый бот](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot) : написан на C#

[Гайд по второму боту](https://firepowered.org/developer/creating-a-steam-trade-bot-with-node-js/) : написан на node.js

В обоих случаях вам необходимы знания программирования, чтобы заставить их работать так, как вам нужно.

Иначе здесь нельзя отправить оффер "POST запросом" или какой-то ссылкой, все намного сложнее.

Comment: Я видел готовые боты на гитхабе. 
Однако они тоже взаимодействуют со стимом через апи.

Если запрос на получение инвентаря мне известен, то вот как отправить tradeoffer остается загадкой

Comment: В обоих реализациях бота доступна отправка оффера. Прочитайте их документацию

Comment: @whý Да, боты используют api для получения инвентарей. Но отправка оффера происходит иным способом, при котором эмулируется подключение акка к стиму. Если для вас документация и исходный код ботов не дают ответа, то, скорее всего, ваш вопрос для вас так и останется открытым.